# Sort List<Integer> using Lambda expression

Tags: java, sorting, lambda

How do i sort this using Lambda expression? 
I am suppose to sort the first 7 numbers and exclude the last number. I saw that IntStream.concat can be used but i need to use Lambda expression to sort.

```
     Random random = new Random();
        List <Integer> lucky = random.ints (1, 64)
                                     .distinct()
                                     .limit(8)
                                     .boxed()
                                     .sorted()
                                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Sort based on what?

Comment: Why insisting on using a lambda?

Comment: Do you need to generate random ints and sort them in one expression or can it be done in 2 expressions?

Comment: @NicholasK
sort based on ascending order.

Comment: @Sweeper Preferably lambda as we are required to implement lambda expression

Comment: @syntagma It can be done in 2 expression, but the problem is I have to use Lambda expression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The requirement of "use a lambda expression" is quite weird. I can fulfil this requirement simply by replace the `.limit` call with

```
.limit(((IntSupplier)() -> 8).getAsInt())
```

Look! I've used a lambda there! `() -> 8`. And then you can move on to sort the problem with `concat` as you said.

Obviously, this is not what you meant.

If you want to put a lambda into the `sort` method to sort the first 7 integers and then always leave the 8th at the end, you could do something like this:

```
Random random = new Random();
List<Integer> unsorted = random.ints(1, 64)
        .distinct()
        .limit(8)
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

// here you need to get the last element that you don't want to sort
int last = unsorted.get(unsorted.size() - 1);
// here is the lambda
List<Integer> sorted = unsorted.stream().sorted((x, y) -> {
    if (Integer.compare(x, y) == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    // if any one of the arguments is the last one...
    if (last == x) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (last == y) {
        return -1;
    }
    return Integer.compare(x, y);
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
// you can also use "List.sort" with the same lambda
```

Note that I personally find this `sorted` method call very unreadable. I can't see at first glance that you are trying to sort everything but the last. In terms of readability, using `concat` would be better.

Comment: Surprisingly, I don't think this implementation of `Comparator` violates the general contract! I so thought it was going to violate the contract.

Comment: I was planning on using Collections.sort(lucky.sublist(0,6)) as i don't see the point in using Lambda just to sort unless i misunderstood what my prof meant when he said 
"I do no expect you to implement some sorting methods to sort them. You are working on functional programming; Lambda can help you to achieve this target. "

Comment: @KevinChee well, you aren’t really writing a sorting method. The lambda only compares two integers.

Answer (score 2):

You can use lambda as a second parameter to `Collections.sort()`, providing sublist as the first parameter:

```
Collections.sort(lucky.subList(0, lucky.size()-1), 
                 (i1, i2) -> i1.compareTo(i2));
```

This will be equivalent to `Collections.sort(lucky.subList(0, lucky.size()-1))`, so you don't really need this lambda expression here.

Another way to do it (not an efficient one) would be using `Stream.concat()`:

```
List<Integer> sorted = Stream.concat(
        lucky.stream()
             .filter(elem -> !elem.equals(lucky.get(lucky.size() - 1))).sorted(),
        Stream.of(lucky.get(lucky.size() - 1)))
                       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note that I am filtering items in the first stream based on value, not the index, as items in `lucky` list are distinct. This could be done based on the index, though that would make performance of that sorting even worse.